How can I waterproof a subfloor that extends past my exterior wall?
I want to bring an exterior wall of my structure in 6" from a subfloor that I built on top of piers. How can I waterproof the to be exposed subfloor?
For background, I am building an accessory structure (storage shed) on top of a foundation with piers. I overbuilt my subfloor by 0.25 sqrft and framed flush to it. The inspector who was looking at other work, saw the framed structure and measured it and wants me to bring it in (accessory structure must be 120 sqrft or less measured from the outside in our city, I'll be 124 once I put up sheathing and siding).
He didn't seem to say I needed to cut my subfloor back, but need to bring a wall in. Though he might not realize that I have the walls built overtop of girders, which are on top of sills bolted down to piers.
Open to other ideas that don't include my taking up the subfloor and move the girders and not having piers hanging out.. (dimensions are 145.75 x 119.25)

Quite a few water proofing compounds you can paint/pour on wood.  Using used engine oil can work, but the inspector might classify it as a hazmat area.

This is kind of a unique situation since the deck was not intended to be exposed to the elements.  However it is a shed and not your home.
I would coat the exposed deck (subfloor) with a waterproofing such as Aquadefense. Then cover with an Adhesive underlayment. Do this prior to installing the exterior wall covering, being sure the membrane is at least 2 inches up the wall
Cover that with decking boards or even left over shingles from the roof.

that seems pretty reasonable, will be kind of funny to haver a deck tail off the back.. maybe i do a deck surround on the whole thing

Yes, I didn't say it wouldn't look a little odd
